# How do I bind the visibility of my stackpanel based on two variables?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to update the visibility of the stackpanel based on the values in varA and varB. Currenty I'm setting it based on the activeA variable.

```
<StackPanel
        Visibility="{Binding varA, Converter={StaticResource VisibleWhenTrueConverter}}">
```

Comment: If you use MVVM, you can add a property `AandB` in your ViewModel.

Comment: A multibinding means logic in a multiconverter. Hence another viewmodel property ( as @Vernou suggests ) is often more convenient. Unless you're going to have lots of these in different views and then a multiconverter could encapulsate repeated logic. Or if you can't have a viewmodel for some reason.